# Android Window already focussed warning javascript Interface

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to interact with the JavaScript through Android. i followed the tutorial found  [here][1].

But I am getting the following warning.system.out.println is also not working

```
WARN/KeyCharacterMap(310): No keyboard for id 0
 WARN/KeyCharacterMap(310): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
 WARN/InputManagerService(66): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44faba68
```

cause of which I am not able to pass values or get the values back

```
webEngine=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webengine);     
        webEngine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webEngine.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");       
        webEngine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()       
        {
             @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
       webEngine.loadUrl("http://www.a11y.in/a11y_fs/");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          // Handle item selection

        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
        case R.id.edit:
            webEngine.loadUrl("javascript:var path =android.path();var newContent=android.newContent();var name = 'myname'; android.toast(name););
            return true;

        case R.id.renarration:

            return true;

        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public String path()
{
    return xPath = "//H3[@id='header']";
}
public String newContent()
{
    return newContent ="my New Home";
}

    public void toast(String x)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hello from js"+x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

plz help

Answer (score 0):

First, those error messages are not related to your code, so you can just ignore them.

Then there seems to be some error with the quotes, there do not match (which also breaks the syntax highlighting in your question)... or it might be only this site which parses it incorrectly...

I also don't see the "path" method in your class, although you are accessing it from javascript. Similarly the "newContent" method.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have updated my code now. i had forgotten to put the functions path and newcontent. I also changed the double quotes to single quotes now. but still it is not working. I get the last warning when I click on the edit menu button.

Comment: my concern is also that the system.out.println also dosent work. so is t tht the method is not getting accessed?

Comment: I tried your code, and it seemed to work for me: I get the "hello from   jsmyname" toast message. The changes I needed to make was: 1) add the missing quote in the loadUrl call, 2) I didn't created the menu xml file, so I created the menu item from code, 3) I created the WebView instance from java code instead of loading a layout and locating it in the layout. But I don't think these changes would have any effect: without the first fix it wouldn't compile, and the last two fixes were not affecting the WebView.